# Is there a option to test the Breaking Changes notifications of facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new in facebook-development.
Is there any option to test the app if all breaking changes of the current [Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) are fixed/included in my app?

I know about the beta.graph api. But I don't know if the old (deprecated) functions are removed in this version.

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can enable them in the [migrations tab](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/363/). In [your Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) > Edit App > Advanced (on the left) > scroll down to Migrations.